# Does anyone have a BaaS alternative to Facebook's PARSE that can handle millions of requests?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, backend

I use Parse in a Freemium Multiplayer Quiz game that naturally needs a lot of users and a lot of data in order to generate any noteworthy income.

The problem is, after my Game table has reached over 500k entries, a simple PFQuery request to this table is not working any more and generating timeout after timeout.

Does anyone have a valid alternative that they have successfully used with millions of entries with an acceptable performance?

Comment: You could self-host using something like SocketCluster http://socketcluster.io/ - Self-hosting is the most flexible and cost-efficient approach in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may noticed Parse will be fully retired after a year-long period ending on **January 28, 2017.**  You can find several alternatives for Parse.com depending upon your requirements.

I would recommend using Google's supported **Firebase**. It has several Good features like Realtime Database Synchronization, Offline support and Nice Documentation etc. See here for [Compelte Feature Set](https://www.firebase.com/features.html)

On the other hand, you can find a comprehensive list of [Parse.com alternative here.](https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer - I work at Hasura.**

You can try out Hasura as an alternative platform for your game application. Hasura is a BaaS with some built in PaaS features. Check out a [Hackernews discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13724118) on Hasura here.

Hasura is built on top  of Postgres, which is one of the most reliable production-grade relational database. Hasura gives you -

- Data APIs over Postgres - you don't have to write ORM type code for retrieving/manipulating data/schema
- Out-of-the-box Auth APIs - you don't have to design, build and maintain a suite of authentication and user management endpoints including OAuth integrations.
- Git push to deploy
- SSH access
- Deploy any custom service (any docker image)
- On your own infrastructure - provides complete access to underlying infra, install Hasura anywhere from bare metal, to cloud providers of your choice.

You can try out Hasura here for a quick demo at https://explore.beta.hasura.io/

Cheers,